# making object and pass it on codeigniter view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, object

i have a query from my model. Now in my controller, the query is inside the loop, now i have two results of objects from my query. How can i make it only one object to be passed in my view?

Here is my code:

```
public function graph_diagnose() {
       $diagnosis = $this->input->post('selectdiagnosis');
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($diagnosis); $i++) {
            $diagname = $this->Adminreport_model->getDiagName($diagnosis[$i]);
            echo json_encode($diagname);
       }
    }
```

now i have a result from my query that is stored in `$diagname` and it consist of two rows inside every query.

Here is the result of `echo json_encode`:

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (2) {
    ["diagnosis"]=>
    string(8) "Headache"
    ["diagnosis_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#24 (2) {
    ["diagnosis"]=>
    string(10) "Sakit Kaau"
    ["diagnosis_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

now what i want is to make it as one object to be json encode. 
where i want an output like this:

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (2) {
    ["diagnosis"]=>
    string(8) "Headache"
    ["diagnosis_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (2) {
    ["diagnosis"]=>
    string(10) "Sakit Kaau"
    ["diagnosis_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array to store the result:

```
$diagnames = [];
```

Inside the for loop:

```
$result = $this->Adminreport_model->getDiagName($diagnosis[$i]);
$diagnames = array_merge($diagnames, $result);
```

But I am wondering why your `getDiagName()` method is returning an array?